# Social Icons closer in Jumbotron

Tags: css, grid, icons

I'm trying to close the gaps/margins between the social icons and have it centered under the text.

[Jumbotron](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtvaY.png)

Here is the code:

```
div class="jumbotron"><!-- Jumbotron -->
<div class="container1">
    <p>A blog to explore, learn, and share Electro Funk, Soul, & Hip Hop Music</p>

        <div id="social"><!-- Social Icons -->
                <div id="twitter" class="col-md-4">
                  <a href="https://twitter.com/FunkFantasizers" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    Twitter
                </div>
                <div id="instagram" class="col-md-4">
                    <i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    Instagram
                </div>
                <div id="soundcloud" class="col-md-4">
                   <a href="https://soundcloud.com/funk-fantasizers" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-soundcloud fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    Soundcloud
                </div>

        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be better to not use separate columns for each icon and instead use one column surrounding them all:

```
<div id="social" class="col-md-12 text-center"><!-- Social Icons -->
  <div id="twitter">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/FunkFantasizers" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    Twitter
  </div>
  <div id="instagram">
    <i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    Instagram
  </div>
  <div id="soundcloud">
    <a href="https://soundcloud.com/funk-fantasizers" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-soundcloud fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    Soundcloud
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok they are now in 3 different rows. How do I make them all inline?

Comment: I did display: inline-block; float: left but nothing happened

Comment: Maybe use `<span>` instead of `<div>`. I'm surprised `display: inline-block;` didn't work. That is what you want to do. Did you add that to each of `#twitter, #instagram, #soundcloud`?

Comment: That worked thank you @Quantastical . I had only put the inblock for the social id. My last question I guess is how to move them to the center. I tried `text-align:center` but its still all the way to the left side.

Comment: Add `text-center` class like so `<div id="social" class="col-md-12 text-center">`.

Comment: @NickBritti Since you appear to be new to StackOverflow, I'd like to point out that it is common for users to Accept an answer if it suits their needs. It is also better to provide "thanks" in the form of Upvotes, instead of comments. Consider [taking the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).